# Setting up Stockfish for Droidfish

Tags: engines, stockfish

I would like to set up Stockfish for the android app [Droidfish](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.petero.droidfish). How do I set up a server for a Windows machine (my linux machine is too weak) using SF13?